# The order protractor/webdriver executes promises

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

the following code gets some text from the web page, gets an inputbox, clears it and sends the text from before to that inputbox:

```
var pText = browser.element(by.css('some_tag')).getText();
var inputbox = browser.element(by.css('[data-aid="login-app-input-username"]'));
inputbox.clear();
// if pText is defined here, everything is ok.
inputbox.then(
    function(e){
        pText.then(
            function(text) {
                e.sendKeys(text);
            });
    });
```

the result is that the `sendKeys()` is done before `clear()`, although the order of the code.
if we drop the declaration of `pText` 3 rows down (after `clear()`) everything works fine.

my question is how can the above code be executes in the right order without dependency to the declaration of `pText`.
btw, i'm aware that `sendKeys()` can receive a promise and this is not the solution i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
var pText = browser.element(by.css('some_tag')).getText();
var inputbox = browser.element(by.css('[data-aid="login-app-input-username"]'));

pText.then(function(text) {
  inputbox.clear().sendKeys(text);
}
```